# Custom camel component using in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm a beginner with Camel Integration and I need to create my custom camel component and use it in a Spring Boot application.

I've tried to generate my component using   **maven archetype** .

So the command is like that:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-component -DarchetypeVersion=2.12.1 -DgroupId=my.tcp.camel.component -DartifactId=my-tcp -Dname=MyTCP -Dscheme=my-tcp

The generated code looks like that

```
public class MyTCPComponent extends DefaultComponent {

    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        Endpoint endpoint = new MyTCPEndpoint(uri, this);
        setProperties(endpoint, parameters);
        return endpoint;
    }
}

public class MyTCPEndpoint extends DefaultEndpoint {

    public MyTCPEndpoint() {}

    public MyTCPEndpoint(String uri, PtTCPComponent component) {
        super(uri, component);
    }

    public MyTCPEndpoint(String endpointUri) {
        super(endpointUri);
    }

    public Producer createProducer() throws Exception {
        return new MyTCPProducer(this);
    }

    public Consumer createConsumer(Processor processor) throws Exception {
        return new MyTCPConsumer(this, processor);
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class MyTCPConsumer extends ScheduledPollConsumer {
    private final MyTCPEndpoint endpoint;

    public MyTCPConsumer(MyTCPEndpoint endpoint, Processor processor) {
        super(endpoint, processor);
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected int poll() throws Exception {
        Exchange exchange = endpoint.createExchange();

        // create a message body
        Date now = new Date();
        exchange.getIn().setBody("Hello World! The time is " + now);

        try {
            // send message to next processor in the route
            getProcessor().process(exchange);
            return 1; // number of messages polled
        } finally {
            // log exception if an exception occurred and was not handled
            if (exchange.getException() != null) {
                getExceptionHandler().handleException("Error processing exchange", exchange, exchange.getException());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyTCPProducer extends DefaultProducer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTCPProducer.class);
    private MyTCPEndpoint endpoint;

    public MyTCPProducer(MyTCPEndpoint endpoint) {
        super(endpoint);
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());    
    }

}
```

and the manifest file created in resources.

I've found out that you can initialize springBoot with FatJar

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootRouter extends FatJarRouter {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("timer://trigger").
                transform().simple("ref:myBean").
                to("log:out", "mock:test");
    }

    @Bean
    String myBean() {
        return "I'm Spring bean!";
    }

}
```

Have somebody integrated their custom component within a SpringBoot Application.

I would prefer to make springboot working with camel auto-discovery component.

Thank you.

Comment: What does your component do? Do you really need your own component to do the stuff? I.e. for TCP connections you could use Camel's [mina-component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-mina2/src/main/docs/mina2-component.adoc) which you can define in your own Spring component as explained [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-boot/src/main/docs/spring-boot.adoc#auto-detecting-camel-routes)

Comment: Do you need to use such old Camel version - 2.12? And what version of Spring Boot do you use? I suggest to use a newer version of Camel. And dont use the FarJarRouter but just standard Spring Boot and Camel. Look at all the examples with Camel and Spring Boot at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Comment: @RomanVottner I want to isolate some separate logic, which is not in mina-component, and neither in netty4-component .

Comment: @ClausIbsen,  thank you. I think the solution for me will be something like this example. **camel-example-spring-boot/**.

Where I'll name the bean as I intended to name the camel-component (i.e. 
    `@Component("my-tcp")
    public class MyBean { }`

Comment: @ClausIbsen what is the way of using **camel-spring-boot** for accessing the route as folow: ` from("my-tcp://foo")
                        .to("my-tcp://bar")` ?

Comment: Have you already [read the official documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/writing-components.adoc#writing-components), especially the part about auto-discorvey? Basically, once you have written the code for your custom component, you should add a file to `META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/my-tcp` with a content of `class=my.tcp.camel.component.MyTCPComponent`. Camel will auto-register the component for you. No need for SB here, it can be used to initialize your routes though

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was trying to add a **Custom camel component** in a camel spring boot.

I've decided to use only as a reference bean instead of component.

```
  @Component("my-tcp")
    @Slf4j
    public class MyTCPComponent {

           public String messageProcess(Exchange msg){
             // do your logic here
           }
  }

@Configuration
public class MyTCPCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:my-tcp")
                .to("bean:my-tcp")
                .to("log:foo");
    }
}
```

and in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

Another solution I was thinking about is to generate camel custom component with maven archetype, and after that to import this as a jar in a spring-boot application.